# Extract values from a correlation matrix according to their p-value in a second matrix

Tags: r, matrix, extract, apply, correlation

I have created a correlation matrix with an external program ([SparCC](https://bitbucket.org/yonatanf/sparcc)). I have calculated p-values from the same data in SparCC as well and I end up with two objects which I imported into R, let's call them `corr` and `pval` and

```
> ncol(corr)==nrow(corr)
[1] TRUE

> ncol(pval)==nrow(pval)
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
> colnames(corr)==rownames(pval)
[1] TRUE ...
```

and the same the other way around.

Since the matrices (or should I be using `data.frame`?) are fairly large (about 1000 items), I would like to extract the significant correlations from the `corr` matrix by looking up their p-value in the `pval` matrix, I have looked into doing something with `apply`:

```
 extracted.values <- apply(corr, nrows(corr), which(pval<0.1))
```

But since the part with `which` isn't really a function, it will output and error.
Since the `which` command output a list of the position in the pval matrix, I'm a bit at loss as to how to retrieve the `colnames` and `rownames` for each desired items.

Is there an easier way of doing what I want, like creating a correlation object from scratch in R (is this at all possible?) which contains both `corr` and `pval` matrices and extracting the significant values? I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265413/comparing-extracting-data-from-matrices-using-python-2-6-1) in Python, but a solution with R would be much appreciated if it's less complicated than what I think it is.

thanks for any help!

edit: the python example doesn't keep headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
corr[pval < 0.1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's certainly easier than what I thought, but it only outputs the array of values in `corr` that match the criteria in `pval`, how to retrieve headers as well?

Comment: Well, it turns out I do not need the headers because the output is an indexed array so for my application, the list of values suffice so this works great.